# Desktop Recording with Ffmpeg: Video and Audio Lag Issues (Windows 10)

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been recording my desktop at 1920x1080 resolution with the following command with no performance issues:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 1 -framerate 60 -probesize 42M -rtbufsize 1024M 
-i desktop -c:v libopenh264 -b:v 30M -g 30 -loopfilter 1 
-profile:v main -allow_skip_frames 1 -an C:\Users\User\Desktop\recording.mkv
```

However, when I try to record my desktop with audio using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 1 -framerate 60 -probesize 42M -rtbufsize 1024M
 -thread_queue_size 512 -i desktop -f dshow -channels 2 -sample_rate 44100 
-i audio="Stereo-mix (Realtek(R) Audio)" -c:v libopenh264 -b:v 30M -g 30 
-loopfilter 1 -profile:v main -allow_skip_frames 1 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 5 
C:\Users\User\Desktop\recording.mkv
```

Performance drops drastically.

I'm able to record real-time Unreal Engine simulations with no problem using the first command, but when I attempt to ALSO record audio, I encounter poor performance even during basic desktop actions like dragging an explorer window across my desktop. The video becomes extremely choppy.

I've already attempted recording in WAV format instead of MP3 by using the "-c:a pcm_s16le" option, as I believe it consumes less processing power, but there appears to be no difference.

I've also experimented with lowering the framerate, but this adjustment also fails to improve the situation.

**UPDATE**

By running two simultaneous ffmpeg commands I get no performance issues.

I created a batch file with following commands:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM
START /b ffmpeg -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 1 -framerate 30 -probesize 42M -rtbufsize 1024M -i desktop -c:v libopenh264 -b:v 30M -g 30 -loopfilter 1 -profile:v high -allow_skip_frames 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -an C:\Users\User\Desktop\recording.mkv
REM
START /b ffmpeg -f dshow -channels 2 -sample_rate 44100 -i audio="Stereo-mix (Realtek(R) Audio)" -c:a pcm_s16le C:\Users\User\Desktop\recording.wav
```

It's not ideal, but audio was reasonably synced with the video when I joined them in Adobe Premiere.

So this makes me a bit more certain that the problem has something to do with FFMPEG having to execute both recording operations in one process instead of a codec performance issue.

I just don't know what else to try besides just running two separate ffmpeg commands at the same time.

**UPDATE 2**

This problem seems to be specific to openh264.

By using vp9 + wav with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 0 -framerate 30 -probesize 42M -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Stereo-mix (Realtek(R) Audio)" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -r 30 -g 90 -s 1920x1080 -quality realtime -speed 5 -threads 8 -row-mt 1 -tile-columns 2 -frame-parallel 1 -qmin 4 -qmax 48 -b:v 4500k -c:a pcm_s16le C:\Users\User\Desktop\recording.mkv
```

I get no slowdown. I didn't test with other codecs though.

Comment: Go with PCM `wav` to ensure audio isn't the cause. -`f wav -c:a pcm -ar 44.1k -ac 2`. Compression performance is better with `-c:v libx264`. Also, swap `-profile:v main -allow_skip_frames 1` with `-preset ultrafast`. What is `-loopfilter 1` ? I'd try without it. Drop bitrate to 20MB, maybe even 15MB. Cut the `-framerate 60` down to `30` if bitrate didn't help. I'm not sure how DirectX does color profiles. This could help, possibly `-profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p`  If all else fails, [there's lossless](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#lossless-recording)

Comment: Hey Jay, thank you for the reply. I have already tried lowering the framerate and using wav to record. The baseline profile doesn't seem to work with libopenh264, so I wasn't able to experiment with that. But I think the video codec is not the issue, because I get great performance if I'm only recording video. Performance plummets if I just record at the same time regardless of my settings.

Comment: Are there perhaps other ways of recording screen + audio to experiment with? Is there, for example, a way to record video and audio separately instead of having both writing to the same .mkv at the same time? I just don't know how I would solve syncing later. Also, are there alternative commands to record audio with ffmpeg in windows that does not use dshow?

Comment: It's common with windows.  It's a long story and kinda infamous with old direct show, active x components, introduction of direct x, it's a nightmare.  https://microsoft.fandom.com/wiki/DirectShow  Check device manager and see if microsoft's default driver is running the device.  If so, see if you can get the actual manufacturer's driver for the audio device. Always worth a shot.

Comment: I know how receptive people are to this, I used to be one.  The actual solution is https://fedoraproject.org/workstation/download  This is an older laptop with only 8GB of ram with Intel 520 Skylake GT2 video.  I've used `ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 30 -i :0.0 -aspect 16:9 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast SCREENCAP.mkv` for years. Simply add `-f pulse -i default` for audio from mic/line-in.  It has `ALSA` or `ALSA+Pulse` and `Pipewire` is great. Add `-f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -c:a pcm_s16le` to route through pulse. With `-f oss -i /dev/dsp1` capture mic and sound simultaneously, with mkv.